# Combine multiple objects that are culled from a json file and return as Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to combine the objects `this.webCustomAlert`, `this.webCustomAuth`,  `this.webCustomEcommerce` into a single object. They all possess common properties. So I would like to go from:

**webCustomAuth**

```
[{ "type":"google-login", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"twitter-login", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"facebook-login", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 }]
```

**webCustomAlert**

```
[{ "type":"desktop-notifications", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"web-notification-page", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"web-notification-settings", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 }]
```

**webCustomEcommerce**

```
[{ "type":"affiliate-url", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"coupons", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"discounts", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 }]
```

To

**webCustomFeatures**

```
[{ "type":"affiliate-url", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"coupons", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"discounts", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"desktop-notifications", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"web-notification-page", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"web-notification-settings", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"google-login", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"twitter-login", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 },{ "type":"facebook-login", "cost":30, "buildTime":2 }]
```

Here is my code:

```
  public webCustomFeatures: any;
  public webCustomAlert: any;
  private webCustomAlertDataPath = './assets/data/web-custom-alert.json';
  public webCustomAuth: any;
  private webCustomAuthDataPath = './assets/data/web-custom-auth.json';
  public webCustomEcommerce: any;
  private webCustomEcommerceDataPath = './assets/data/web-custom-ecommercejson';

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.webCustom = this.httpClient.get(this.webCustomDataPath);
    this.webCustomAlert = this.httpClient.get(this.webCustomAlertDataPath);
    this.webCustomAuth = this.httpClient.get(this.webCustomAuthDataPath);
    this.webCustomEcommerce = this.httpClient.get(this.webCustomEcommerceDataPath);
  }

  public getAllWebCustomAlert(): Observable<any> {
    return this.webCustomAlert;
  }

  public getAllWebCustomAuth(): Observable<any> {
    return this.webCustomAuth;
  }

  public getAllWebCustomEcommerce(): Observable<any> {
    return this.webCustomEcommerce;
  }

  public getAllWebCustomFeatures(): Observable<any> {
    const webCustomFeatures = [];
    webCustomFeatures.push(this.webCustomAlert);
    webCustomFeatures.push(this.webCustomAuth);
    webCustomFeatures.push(this.webCustomEcommerce);
    return webCustomFeatures;
  }
```

I keep getting the error message `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'any[]'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array of observables which is not an observable, you want to combineLatest

```
public getAllWebCustomFeatures(): Observable<any> {
  return combineLatest(this.webCustomAlert, this.webCustomAuth, this.webCustomEcommerce);
}
```

Will emit and array once all three have emitted then you can destructure the array into the values.

```
getAllWebCustomFeatures().subscribe(([webCustomAlert, webCustomAuth, webCustomEcommerce]) => {
  //Do stuff with the destructured values here
});
```